# vitejs treat all .scss files as css modules

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, vite, css-modules

I am working with a legacy package in a monorepo and am [including in the optimizeDeps array](https://vitejs.dev/config/dep-optimization-options.html#optimizedeps-include) - is it possible to tell Vite to treat all .scss files it sees as CSS Modules files?

> Originally asked in the vite discord: https://discord.com/channels/804011606160703521/1217522070343254016

The problem is that this legacy package has all its css modules files as plain `.scss` files instead of `.module.scss` which vite expects, and so I see this error:

```
The requested module '/@fs/Users/jakxz/go/src/.../components/fields/EditableField/EditableField.scss' does not provide an export named 'default''
```

`EditableField.js` is a compiled ESM react component that attempts to do

```
import styles from './EditableField.scss';
```

Comment: Have you tried https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options#css-modules option?

Comment: Yes but all the config I’ve tried does not work. What would you suggest?

Comment: To be explicit, I know that CSS modules is enabled by default but I’m trying to change the rules of which files the “loader” applies to. I’m also asking if this is even possible or intentionally not possible.

Comment: So it's looking to me like this is not possible... yet. I do have a suggestion on making module imports opt-in via a query param: https://discord.com/channels/804011606160703521/1218418479753859102

Answer (score 0):

By configuring **vite.config.js** file like below, all **.scss** files will be treated as CSS Modules files, regardless of their file extension:

```
// vite.config.js
export default {
  optimizeDeps: {
    include: ['**/*.scss'], // Include all .scss files
  },
  css: {
    modules: {
      // Enable CSS Modules for all .scss files
      localsConvention: 'camelCaseOnly',
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score -1):

In your vite.config.js `export default { css: { preprocessorOptions: { scss: { modules: true } } } }`

This will ensure that Vite interprets all .scss files as CSS Modules

Comment: This does not work.